# jQuery event when JSON is received - one time URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to scrape a site that uses lots of ajax effects to show data in a table.

There is some data returned via JSON when you interact with the site.

I know the URL and how to construct it but the server returns a `HTTP 410 status` if I try and re-request this JSON (I guess the server is expiring the data).

I have one chance to capture the data and I'm looking for a jQuery function, something like `onJSONResourceReceived` would be nice so that I can catch the response and store it in a variable.

Either a callback or a way to cache the data in a variable would be great.

Or if there is already a variable that stores all JSON resource already received in memory, that is even better.

All the functions I've looked at are for situations where you know or can re-request the URL.

This question is similar but for CasperJS:
[How to get the response after a POST request in CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21705668/536546)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you get this code to run?

Comment: i'm using casperJS.  This allows you to execute javascript (therefore jQuery) in the headless browser context

Comment: Couldn't you hook-up your code to their ajax promise and implement your own success() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [$.ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/)

> Attach a function to be executed whenever an Ajax request completes
>   successfully.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function( event, request, settings ) {

});
```